# How to generate a random decimal number in love2D?

Tags: lua, love2d

I tried generating a random decimal number between (lets say between 0.3 and 0.8) in love2d using the following code:

```
x=math.random(0.3, 0.8)
print(x)
```

but what happens is it generates 0.3 every single time I run the program and the 0 in 0.4 kind of flickers (in the sense like it changes to 1).

If it helps, here's a screen record of what happens https://vimeo.com/632949687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is underspecified. Here are two simple solutions; they're not equivalent.

This generates random numbers in the set {0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8}:

```
math.random(3,8)/10
```

This generates random numbers in the interval [0.3,0.8):

```
0.3+(0.8-0.3)*math.random()
```

Comment: The "it generates 0.3 every time I run the program" implies they may also be forgetting to call `math.randomseed()` on startup.

Answer (score 1):

In LÖVE there is a platform independent version of `random()` present.
https://love2d.org/wiki/love.math.random
With no need to use of `math.randomseed()` or `love.math.setRandomSeed()`.
For float numbers in the range 0 and 1 simply use...
`love.math.random()`

'but what happens is it generates 0.3 every single time'
Same here, so the simpliest way seems to be @lhf' example.

Answer (score -1):

check the function

```
function random(min, max, precision)
    local precision = precision or 0
    local num = math.random()
    local range = math.abs(max - min)
    local offset = range * num
    local randomnum = min + offset
    return math.floor(randomnum * math.pow(10, precision) + 0.5) / math.pow(10, precision)
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. However its too complicated for as a simple objective as mine. But I will surely use your code when I need it.

Comment: It's okay, I understand but I wanted to give you a complex for a good understanding.